# Using R to Manipulate Cell Text Colour in Excel File (xlsx package, maybe, or whatever else might work)?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

In essence, the goal is to look for keywords in excel cells, if a the word appears at least once in the cell, I would like to text in that cell to be blue and the particular word I am looking for to be red (so the cell would end up having both blue and red text)

Is that possible to do directly with R, somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: xlsx allows setting the cell style see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf
p.15

Comment: @Linus yes, but that formats the whole cell, and not just a part of it; so I don't think I would be able to have both red and blue?

Comment: Sorry, no I do not think that is possible. I thought you want the background blue and the text red... sorry. The other good xlsx packages (openxlsx, writexls) do not support it either :-/